# React app errors when pushing to GitHub pages

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages

When pushing my React app to GitHub Pages, I continue to get various error messages. Some projects when viewed through GitHub just have a blank screen, others have `404 page not found` errors, others bring up a page telling me that "this project was bootstrapped with create react app."

I have tried using several different tutorials to deploy the projects in different ways.

- [this one](https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f)
- [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8s4Ng-re0E&t=653s)

The one and only project I got to work I used `"deploy": "gh pages -b master -d build"`. I have been installing gh pages using `npm install gh-pages --save-dev` on my projects.

This is an example of the error I get in my terminal:

```sh
sh: gh: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! count-up@0.1.0 deploy: `gh pages -b master -d build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the count-up@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/connortwele/.npm/_logs/2020-08-08T15_59_50_754Z-debug.log
MacBook-Pro:count-up connortwele$
```

Comment: The command is `gh-pages`, not `gh pages`. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages#command-line-utility

Comment: ah I see, on that instance I had mistyped it. Unfortunately running through everything again making sure to use gh-pages did not fix the problem. This time my site published with a "404 page not found"

Comment: You'd have to provide a [mre] for help with that - make sure you *have* run a build of the site and its output is in `build/`.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help, I will work on that and see what I can come to